# How to move a model with all the bones?

Tags: modeling, bones

When I try to move my model with all the bones I can't.

I'm going to Object Mode and I select everything and then I'm going to Edit Mode and I try to move the model with the arrows but I can't.

[image]

Does someone know the answer?

Thanks so much.

Comment: move them in "pose mode", since you only want to move the whole body, you just need to move the bottom bone (the one of circle shape with 4 arrow out of it) in pose mode.

I recommend you watching some tutorials, this is a very basic question.

Comment: Thank you. I'm there. I can't find the tutorials for my version and from one version to another the options are different. My version is 2.74.

Comment: I'll find the way to move the whole body. Thank you